# Getting values out of string of values

Tags: string, swift, search, substring

I my app can read this string out of a QR Code, the amount of values differs per code
Example:

```
"<23><423><12><54>"
```

I would like to get each value which are separated by < & > 
I thought of a loop which prints out each value. but im not really sure how to search for the values.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use a regular expression/regex. Search for "regex match c#". I'll post an answer when I'm back at the computer if you haven't solved it by then :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution:

```
let string = "<23><423><12><54>"

let nsString = string as NSString // (Works better with NSRegularExpression)
let regex = NSRegularExpression(pattern: "<(\\d+)>", options: nil, error: nil)!
regex.enumerateMatchesInString(nsString, options: nil, range: NSMakeRange(0, nsString.length)) {
    (result, _, _) -> Void in
    let code = nsString.substringWithRange(result.rangeAtIndex(1))
    println(code)
}
```

`"<(\\d+)>"` is a regular expression pattern that matches one or more
digits enclosed in `<...>`, and the parentheses define a "capture group"
which is then extracted with `result.rangeAtIndex(1)`.